Create a blank page and add text content using PyPDF2: module 'PyPDF2' has no attribute 'pdf'
Using this method to add create a blank page, add text to it and then append the page to a pdf.
def add_text_to_blank_page(pdf_writer, text):
    # Create a new blank page
    page = PyPDF2._pdf.PageObject.create_blank_page(width=612, height=792)  # Standard US Letter size
    # Create a PDF text object
    pdf_text = PyPDF2.pdf.TextStringObject(text)
    # Create a PDF text element
    text_element = PyPDF2.pdf.TextObject()
    text_element.setFont("Helvetica", 12)  # Set font and font size
    text_element.textLines.append(pdf_text)
    # Add the text element to the page
    page.addText(text_element)
    # Add the page to the PDF writer
    pdf_writer.add_page(page)

the first line is erroring:
AttributeError: module 'PyPDF2' has no attribute 'pdf'
I checked the documents for PyPDF2, the module should be there, I am clearly doing something wrong.
What is wrong here ?

What is your PyPDF2 version?

Successfully installed PyPDF2-3.0.1 typing-extensions-4.7.1

I think its fixed, I just removed 'pdf' from the line

but theres other things with the other lines.

how do I acces TextStringObject? PyPDF2.TextStringObject("blah") AttributeError: module 'PyPDF2' has no attribute 'TextStringObject'

PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.

Try to import like this:
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from PyPDF2.generic import TextStringObject, NameObject

So, it will be:
pdf_text = TextStringObject(text)

Also, PyPDF2 project will no longer continue, instead use pypdf.
Its latest version is pypdf 4.2.0
https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/
